# Triceps Pushdown - Why Pain in Shoulders

Tags: pain, shoulders, triceps

I was Doing Triceps Pushdown & I am getting more **pain in shoulder**s instead of Triceps, If i put less weights, than i dont get shoulders pain, so is it better to reduce weights or may i **continue with more weights**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake with tricep pushdowns (althoguh it doesn't feel like it) You roll your shoulders over the weight to help you push it down. There's a lot of techniques on the internet out there to fix this but I find leaning forwards whilst keeping my back straight and head forwards to ensure I focus entirely on my triceps without moving shoulders or elbows tends to do the trick.

Comment: @USer345738380 if you can't do at least 8 reps on a weight without rolling your shoulders then the weight is too heavy and you should drop it. I feel on tricep pushdowns light weight still helps me focus and contract on the muscle as long as you get a good squeeze when extended